# Can someone help me understand where this 'no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been trying to trouble shoot this for an hour and a half now and I could really use some help trying to debug this error I am facing. Thanks in advance for any help.

To start, I have this view in `topics/show.html.haml`

```
- if current_user_is_admin?
= button_to t('.move'), move_topic_path(@topic),
  method: :get, class: 'btn btn-mini', id: 'move_link'
```

When you click this button you are directed to this route under my Topics Controller:

```
def move_topic
  @topic = Topic.find_by(id: params[:id])
  render template: 'topics/move'
end
```

From there you move onto the `topics/move` template which as of now contains this code:

```
1. = form_for @topic, topic_path(@topic) do |f|
2.   #value_select.chosen= t('.move_to')
3.   = f.select :forum_id, Forum.all.collect { |forum| forum.name }
```

When I get to the template, I receive this error:

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

This error is driving me insane. I don't understand where the problem is. I've looked at these two files specified:

```
app/views/topics/move.html.haml:1:in 
`_app_views_topics_move_html_haml__1847509286908821786_70131052656700'
app/controllers/topics_controller.rb:50:in `move_topic'
```

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with my controller. I ran a debugger statement which grabs the topic. There is something wrong with my form but the error is not descriptive enough. I'm not trying to convert anything into an Integer. Why is it raising this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be

```
 form_for @topic, url: topic_path(@topic)
```

Or even just

```
form_for @topic
```

Which should default to the above url. The reason for the error message is that rails expects the second argument to a hash of options, so it is checking stuff like `options[:url]`. Since you were instead passing a string rails ends up calling doing `topic_path(@topic)[:url]` which isn't valid since you can't use a symbol with the [] method on a string.

The error page should have allowed you to look at the framework portion of the backtrace (although this is usually collapsed by default) (ie what happens inside `form_for`) - looking at this may have made it easier to see what was happening

Comment: Thank God. It finally works, thanks a lot Frederick.